# Transference of weights leading to smaller model (Keras)

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to insert a `dropout` layer into my model. So I load the old model, create a new model architecture, and transfer the weights.

However when I save the new model, the memory footprint is a lot smaller:

113 megabytes vs original 338 megabytes.
I suspect I must be making a mistake in the process, but the model seems to save and is running. The accuracy is about 15% lower but can't tell if that is dropout effect.

Here is my code:

```
def add_dropout(layer_num = None, prob = .4):

#layer num is where you will insert the dropout layer


     model = load_model(model_path)
     layers_set1 = [layer for layer in model.layers[:layer_num + 1]]
     x = layers_set1[-1].output
     x = Dropout(prob, name = "drop_test1")(x)
     layers_set2 = [layer for layer in model.layers[layer_num+1:]]
     for layer in layers_set2:
        print(layer)
        x = layer(x)



     final_model = Model(inputs = layers_set1[0].input, outputs = x)

     for num, layer in enumerate(layers_set1):
         weights = layer.get_weights()
         final_model.layers[num].set_weights(weights)

     for num, layer in enumerate(layers_set2, start = len(layers_set1) + 1):
         weights = layer.get_weights()
         final_model.layers[num].set_weights(weights)


     final_model.save(os.path.join(save_dir, "dropout_added.h5"))
```

Comment: Dropout is only used in the training process, and no cell will be actually dropped from the model. Only model pruning can affect the model actual size https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably using an advanced optimizer like Adam, which has a state that is saved if its available, and its usual size is 2x the number of parameters of the model.

So if you load the model and save a new one based on it, the optimizer state is lost and the model file size is reduced. If you save the model after training then the optimizer state will be saved and you should get a similar model file size.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. This makes sense.